# Создать проект с поддержкой QT

Tags: установка, qt

Установил `minGW + Qt 4.8 + Qt Creator 2.8.0`. Захожу в создать проект - нет проекта с поддержкой `QT`.

Как настроить или по-другому установить? Раньше была сборка offline - установил и радуйся, а сейчас такая только пятерка. (Мне нужна четверка).

Comment: mingw 4.4.0 установили?

Comment: http://risovach.ru/upload/2013/08/mem/zhirinovskij_25864724_orig_.png

Comment: mingw-get-inst-20120426 то есть наверное 4.6

Comment: да, вот и жирик говорит ;)

Comment: я пару месяцев назад мучился с этим, пока не нашел подходящую версию mingw. В противном случае инсталлятор Qt предупреждает, что нормально не установится.

Comment: c Qt Creator 2.8 не работал, но в более ранних версиях вроде бы это решалось указанием вручную в настройках пути до mingw. Где конкретно эти настройки лежат на память не скажу, под рукой сейчас среды нету, но могу вечером посмотреть, по ощущениям где-то в вернем меню по центру, а далее то ли параметры сборки, то ли с++. А может и прописывание в path поможет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант посмотрите на [эти](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/external-binary-packages/Qt-Builds/) сборки, там же лежат [компиляторы](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/) которыми их собирают. Насколько я помню QtCreator присутствует в их составе.

Добавлено чуть позже:

Скачал сборку x64-Qt-4.8.5+qtcreator-2.8.0-RC-(gcc-4.8.1-seh-rev1).7z, распаковал. В переменной PATH прописал путь Qt64-4.8.5\bin и ported64\bin. Далее в каталоге Qt64-4.8.5\bin создаём файл qt.conf такого содержания:

```
[Paths]
Prefix = D:/programs/prog_dev/cpp/Qt64-4.8.5
```

D:/programs/prog_dev/cpp - каталог куда я распаковал загруженный архив.

Теперь можно запускать QtCreator, Assistant и т.д. проекты создаются и компилируются, справка читается.